# Open and download pdf using cordova javascript without Plugin ios and Android both

Tags: javascript, cordova

Need perform following tasks:

1. Open pdf from a URL
2. Should be able to View it
3. Download it
4. Select it from file explorer.

Please suggest answers in detail as I am new to javascript. :-)

Comment: The standard anchor element should do the trick. <a href="myPDF.pdf">My PDF File</a>

Comment: Just tried it. But it is taking me out of app. How to handle this?